# Filter blur CSS property from Dart

Tags: dart

Dart filter blur doesn't work with Safari, Chrome... Why ?

```
<h1>This text will blur in Firefox, not in Webkit</h1>


import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:core';

main() {
  document.querySelector('h1').style.filter = 'blur(5px)';
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you add it using CSS instrad of Dart?

Comment: Of course it works from CSS ! But, what I need is to control the blur on elements dynamicaly from my Dart code according to events on my webpage. Thank you Günter for your answers.

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome and Firefox in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/f896dfe2a6a8255a0569) and it works in Firefox when applied using Dart and CSS and does *not* work in Chrome not matter if I use Css or Dart. This seems to be a Chrome issue and is not related to Dart.

Comment: Ok, it is an Dart issue. If you use `-webkit-filter` instead of `filter` in CSS it works in Chrome. Dart should replace `filter` with `-webkit-filter` automatically in Chrome. Can you please create a bug report in http://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Dart doesn't replace `filter` with `-webkit-filter` in Chrome but it should. There are plans to support unprefixed `filter` in Chrome (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/R2gCfHjNgKs) but it's not clear when this will ship. It might be worth creating a bug report in http://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/new so the prefix gets added automatically for Chrome.